# У участника нет прав доступа комментировать это сообщение

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

при попытке написать комментарий, когда не залогинен на сайт показывается сообщение

> У участника нет прав доступа комментировать это сообщение

По-моему, оно как-то коряво сформулировано - может поменяем?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: а как можно не вошедши на сайт написать комментарий? У меня при после нажатия ссылки "Добавить комментарий" появляется всплывающее окно с предложением зарегистрироваться и набрать 50 баллов репутации

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHc00.png - там кстати не согласован падеж; и вроде чтобы оставлять сообщения, не нужна дополнительная репутация

Comment: @mymedia, какая-то хромофича, что он после перезапуска восстановил страницу из кэша (или, понятия не имею, откуда взял) и я там показываюсь залогиненным, но реально логин слетел и при попытке что-то сделать что-то идёт не так. Если страницу обновить, то будешь не залогинен. Кстати, можно попробовать в другой складке выйти, но мне лень)

Comment: Задал [вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302617/339911) для прояснения ситуации.

Answer (score 5):

> Вы не можете комментировать это сообщение

Answer (score 5):

> Для комментирования сообщений требуется войти на сайт

Это для случая, если то сообщение только незарегистрированным показывается

Comment: Войти недостаточно. Нужно еще иметь соответствующую [привилегию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @alexolut, там вроде есть правильное сообщение?

Comment: Где "там" и что есть "правильное"?

Comment: Что-то про число баллов.

Answer (score 0):

Может

"Недостаточно прав для добавления комментария"?

Или

"Только зарегистрированные пользователи могут добавлять комментарии"?

Comment: [Предлагается](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302617/339911) поменять исходную строку для начала.

Answer (score -1):

Оригинальное сообщение выглядит так:

> User does not have permission to comment on this post

Поэтому предлагаю не искажать смысл и не делать предположений, а перевести как есть. Примерно так:

> Участнику не разрешено комментировать это сообщение

Comment: Почему "участнику"? Ведь сообщение видит тот, кто пытается комментировать. Должно быть "вам".

Comment: @Qwertiy потому что "User". Может эта строка ещё в каких-то других контекстах используется, например, у модераторов. Вот будет весело, если ему напишем "Вам нельзя комментировать" :)

Comment: Но это же нелогично...

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда надо предлагать изменить исходный текст на MSE.

Comment: Вообще-то английский не стоит переводить буквально на русский, иначе получится что корявое вроде "Пользователь не имеет прав доступа для добавления комментария к этому посту", в английском это правила грамматики, но в русском будет криво.

Comment: "Не разрешено" звучит как если бы запрет установили те, чье имя нельзя произносить (политбюро цэкакапээсэс например, или там царь-батюшка).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan вообще, меня удивляет, какое широкое обсуждение вышло из-за достаточно редкой ситуации. На MSE, судя по голосам, эта тема тоже многим интересна.